# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect under load

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, serversocket, load-testing

I'm running a loadtest on a brand new Windows 2008 64 bit machine.
The loader is a Java Applet which uses an HttpURLConnection to post requests to the server which is listening on a ServerSocket.accept(), both loader and server are running on the same machine.

On my old Windows 2003 server I was able to load over a 1000 users using this configuration.
However, with the new server, when loading around 400 sessions the loader starts throwing the following exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
...
```

It looks as if the server or the machine is running out of some resource. 
The ServerSocket backlog is set to 256 and it looks like it is not being exhausted.
The machine cpu utilization is less than 10% and the server has plenty of available memory.
Observing the client and server using Visual VM it looks like both are functioning properly at the time of the problem.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Update: eventually I figured that when running a 32 bit Java VM on a 64 bit Windows server the scalability is reduced by about 50%. It looks as if some resources used by Java on a 64 bit machine takes about twice as memory compared to 32 bit machine. I still did not figure exactly which resources has run out when this problem occurs. eventually we ported our code to run using a 64 bit Java VM and this resolved the problem.

Comment: Update2: finally figured out that the root cause for this problem was that the server process was stuck in a lengthy garbage collection cycle thus causing the client connection to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe server is rejecting connections due to lack of some other resources? Each HTTP requests will require opening TCP connection, which under Linux uses 'file' (I'm not Linux expert, so please correct me if I'm wrong). So sometimes CPU and memory are low, but HTTP server opens hundreds of files which in the end causes failure and any further request will be rejected.

I'm not sure if this applies to Windows as well, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There are some additional limitations imposed in 2008 that were not part of previous versions.  I would start here... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.12.network.aspx